# Is there a standard map function for trees in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tree, map-function

I need to write a non-recursive function that transforms my tree. But I can't use my own map function for trees. Is there a standard map function for trees in Haskell?

```
data BTree a = Tip a | Bin (BTree a) (BTree a)
exapmeTree = Bin (Bin (Tip [1,2,3,4,5]) (Tip [3,9,7])) (Bin (Tip [6,7,8,9]) (Tip [8,2,1]))
myReverse list = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] list

reverseTree tree = map myReverse tree
```

Comment: Did you consider the [DeriveFunctor](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor) Haskell language extension ?

Comment: Note that, even assuming a tree map function, `map myReverse tree` could only work if you have a tree of lists. Is that what you need?

Comment: @chi the `BTree` should have a generic type. `myReverse` is an example. I need a generic `map` function to iterate over the tree.

Comment: a generic map only changes the contents of each value inside a tree, it does not change the tree structure at all. just so it is clear. :) thus `map myReverse tree` change each element `x` inside the tree into `myReverse x`. but `myReverse` expects its argument to be a list. `myReverse`  can't work if `x` for example is a number. In Haskell, all elements in a given tree will have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write the fmap function yourself, as demonstrated by Rik.

Or you can use the fmap function provided by the automatically generated Functor instance.

Testing under `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XDeriveFunctor
 λ> 
 λ> data BTree a = Tip a | Bin (BTree a) (BTree a)  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
 λ> 
 λ> exampleTree = Bin (Bin (Tip [1,2,3,4,5]) (Tip [3,9,7])) (Bin (Tip [6,7,8,9]) (Tip [8,2,1]))
 λ> 
 λ> reverseTree = fmap reverse exampleTree
 λ> 
 λ> reverseTree 
 Bin (Bin (Tip [5,4,3,2,1]) (Tip [7,9,3])) (Bin (Tip [9,8,7,6]) (Tip [1,2,8]))
 λ>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've created the `BTree` type yourself, no, there is no standard function for it. You can quite easily write a `Functor` instance yourself though.

```hs
instance Functor BTree where
  fmap f (Tip a)   = Tip (f a)
  fmap f (Bin l r) = Bin (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
```

Now you can write `reverseTree tree = fmap myReverse tree`.

Note that `fmap` is the exact same as `map` in the context of lists, but it is more generic, meaning it works for any `Functor` instance.

Comment: Doesn't `fmap my reverse tree` have type `BTree [a] -> BTree [a]`?  I.e. it requires a tree with lists at the tip, and reverses those lists.  It doesn't really reverse the tree per se.

Comment: @pat Yes, and that's exactly what the question is asking for.